# SharePoint 2016: Clearing the Distributed Logon Token Cache

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, login, cache, distributedcache

Is running "Clear-SPDistributedCacheItem -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache" PowerShell supported on a SharePoint 2016 farm?  I can't find it specific to that version anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is supported as couple of days back we ran the same command due to some issue with DC.

We had a support ticket opened with MSFT, one of step contains that command. This command only clear the cache which should not cause issue

Comment: Here is the official post:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219715%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Supported in 2016